# Problemas con menú al hacer dropdown wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, menú

Hola que tal? Estoy haciendo mi web en wordpress y me encuentro con el siguiente problema. Al hacer dropdown a un submenú en cierto tamaños de pantalla la lista que se despliega se oculta detrás del contenido de la web ¿Alguien podrá ayudarme? ¡Se lo agradezco!

Aquí dejó capturas del comportamiendo del menú en 3 resoluciones diferentes.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Fragmento del código dónte está el header

```
<?php
/**
 * The header for our theme
 *
 * This is the template that displays all of the <head> section and everything up until <main id="content">
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-files/#template-partials
 *
 * @package Milos
 */

?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">

    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>

<div id="page" class="site">
    
    <a class="skip-link screen-reader-text" href="#content"><?php esc_html_e( 'Skip to content', 'milos' ); ?></a>

    <header id="masthead" class="header <?php milos_the_header_classes(); ?>" role="banner">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="mast-head-wrap">
                        <div class="site-brand">
                            <?php if ( has_custom_logo() ) {
                                the_custom_logo();
                            } ?>

                            <?php if ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) : ?>
                                <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
                            <?php else : ?>
                                <p class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></p>
                            <?php endif; ?>

                            <?php $description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' ); ?>
                            <?php if ( $description || is_customize_preview() ) : ?>
                                <p class="site-description"><?php echo $description; /* WPCS: xss ok. */ ?></p>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            
 <div class="telefono"><?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Tel') ) : endif; ?></div>
                            
                        </div>

                        <button class="btn-sm menu-toggle" aria-controls="primary-menu" aria-expanded="false">
                            <span class="genericon genericon-menu"></span>
                            <?php esc_html_e( 'Menu', 'milos' ); ?>
                        </button>

                        <nav id="site-navigation" class="navigation-main" role="navigation">
                            <?php wp_nav_menu( array(
                                'theme_location' => 'menu-1',
                                'menu_id'        => 'primary-menu',
                            ) ); ?>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </header>
```

---

Aquí se ve como el se genera un scroll y ahí es que se despliega el menú ¿Alguien tiene idea de como puedo resolverlo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: agregale un z-index bien alto, para que se superponga a los demas elementos, https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: Coloqué el z-index pero el problema persiste.
Acabo de notar que no es que el menú se oculta detras de las cosas sino que se genera un scroll al desplegarlo

Comment: tengo el mismo probelma, donde colocaste el overflow-x?